# Django-channels, how to use mocks

Tags: django-channels, python-mock, django-unittest

I build this chat website, and I'd like to test this functionnality:

- if you send a message and the user is online, send message via websocket: Tested
- if you send a message and the user is offline, send a push notification (it's a REST call).

Obviously, in my test, I don't want to do the REST call. I'd like to mock the function "push_notif".

But, when I use unittest.patch, the function is not mocked in the consumer (probably because of some async stuff). How can I mock this "push_notif" function

Comment: Can you post the code and the test?

Comment: Here is a gist
https://gist.github.com/afouchet/514db2a496c4f29f1ec642c82c085df8

Answer (score 1):

Out of solution, I made a decorator for my function "push_notif". If in test, it writes in a file "func.__name__,args,kwargs", then I read this file in my test to see if the right call was passed.

Ugly, but getting things done